# Links under Bootstrap dropdown menu won't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, dropdownbox

I have a sam problem here.. I'm working with Wordpress theme and I'm trying to add a dropdown menu (for language option) on navigation bar. Here's my code from header.php link just won't work :( Can anybody help me on this?

Here's my code:

```
<header id="masthead" class="<?php echo of_get_option('header_layout'); ?>">
<div class="mid-content clearfix">
<div id="site-logo">
<?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
    <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>">
</a>
<?php else:?>
    <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
    <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>

<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
<div class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'accesspress_parallax' ); ?></div>

    <?php 
    $sections = of_get_option('parallax_section');
    if(of_get_option('enable_parallax')==1 && of_get_option('enable_parallax_nav')==1 && !empty($sections) ): ?>
    <ul class="nav single-page-nav">
    <?php
    $home_text = of_get_option('home_text');
        if(of_get_option('show_slider')== "yes" && !empty($home_text)) : ?>
            <li class="current"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>#main-slider"><?php echo esc_attr($home_text); ?></a></li>
        <?php endif;

        foreach ($sections as $single_sections): 
            if($single_sections['layout'] != "action_template" && $single_sections['layout'] != "blank_template" && $single_sections['layout'] != "googlemap_template" && !empty($single_sections['page'])) :
            $title = get_the_title($single_sections['page']); ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>#section-<?php echo $single_sections['page']; ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></a></li>
            <?php 
            endif;
        endforeach; ?>


              <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropdown-toggle lng_cc" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                  Jezik <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdpwn_cc" role="menu">
                <li class="lang_lili">
                    <a href="http://clubberschoice.eu"><img src="http://clubberschoice.eu/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Croatia.png"/> hrvatski </a>
                </li>
                <li class="lang_lili">
                    <a href="http://clubberschoice.eu/en/"><img src="http://clubberschoice.eu/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/United-Kingdom.png"/> engleski </a>
                </li>

                </ul>
              </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: plz also post your
dropdown_cc and lang_lili css code..

Comment: .main-navigation ul ul li.lang_lili {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
 padding: 5px 0;
}

.main-navigation ul ul li.lang_lili:hover > a {
 color:#D95B4C;
 border-radius:5px;
}

Comment: I don't have dropdown_cc, I must have forgotten to delete it from the code.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. The problem was in state 'current' that happened on click. That was blocking the link action.

So I googled :) and I insert this code:

```
$('ul li#cc_nav_lang').click(function(){ $('ul li#cc_nav_lang').removeClass('current');});

$('li.dropdown ul').find('a').on('click', function() {
window.location = $(this).attr('href');});
```

And now is working. You can check it on www.clubberschoice.eu/en/ how it's work. 
Thank you all!